# How to deal with the strangeness number when I insert the data from CSV into MySQL by using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

there is a CSV file which have several columns, for example:

> (ID, price, address)

but in the price column, there is some strangeness

for example, if there is no price data in one row, it will shows "-"

also, if the price is much bigger. it will have commas between numbers, it will shows: $1,123,234.12

how to deal with those situation?

for example:

> (1000, -, new york)
>
> (1001, $1,100,100, boston)
>
> (1002, $100, LA)

in the CSV files, when using PHP to insert those data into MySQL database, it should shows:

> (1000, 0, new york)
>
> (1001, 1100100, boston)
>
> (1002, 100, LA)

in the database

Does anyone tell me how to handle this? I have no idea how to deal with those situation.

Comment: Are you able to change delimiter to semicolon `;` or tab character `\t`? Also, `str_replace('-', '0', $row[1])`

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. These things ('$','-',',') should not be in your csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some cleanup before importing, something like

```
function csv_clean($csv_file){
    $data = file_get_contents($csv_file);
    $data = str_replace(' -,', ' NULL,', $data);
    $data = preg_replace('/(?<=\d),(?=\d)|\$/', '', $data);
    file_put_contents($csv_file, $data);
}

csv_clean('data.csv');
```

This will save the CSV file in the required format and then you can import it.